# SessionNotCreatedError using MS Access VBA. Chrome = 122.0.6261.112, chromedriver=112.0.5615.49

Tags: vba, ms-access, selenium-chromedriver

Usually, when i get these conflicts i simply go to "https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads" and update the driver.

But no matter what i do or which version i install i get a version mismatch.

Can anyone help?

Typical Error message below

> SessionNotCreatedError
> session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 112
> Current browser version is 122.0.6261.112 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
> (Driver info: chromedriver=112.0.5615.49 (bd2a7bcb881c11e8cfe3078709382934e3916914-refs/branch-heads/5615@{#936}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.22631 x86_64)

Comment: Chromedriver got depracated starting from 115, you need to change your logic as now that is built with selenium, I'm not quite sure if they ever updated that on selenium for office (I haven't seen an update on the github project of it since 2016 and I'm not quite sure if the forks have it, the one from zc2com seems promising but I have moved to python for selenium tasks)

Answer (score 0):

Download the most recent, stable chrome and chromedriver versions from here -

https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable

Check your chromedriver version from the command line -

PS C:\Users\david\appdata\Local\SeleniumBasic> .\chromeDriver -v

ChromeDriver 122.0.6261.111 (9d4c1072d ...

Check your Chrome version from Chrome > Menu > Help > About Chrome

Chrome is up to date
Version 122.0.6261.112 (Official Build) (64-bit)

This code works on Windows 11 with Microsoft® Access® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2402 Build 16.0.17328.20124) 64-bit VBA -

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

    Sub sbChromeDriver()
        Dim bt As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
        bt.Start
        bt.Get "https://www.google.com"
        bt.Wait 2000
        bt.Window.Maximize
        bt.Wait 2000
        bt.Quit
    End Sub
```